# Названый отец (мать). А названная семья - это о том же?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> Однако если сегодня в России приглашение стать **названым отцом или
>   матерью** нередко лишь знак внимания или расположения со стороны
>   друзей, то в Сербии кум считается в таком случае чуть ли не святым,
>   потому как тут верят, что от него зависят и здоровье, и благополучие,
>   и благосостояние ребёнка. В жизни каждого человека здесь присутствует
>   несколько столь близких и дорогих сердцу людей и так много
>   бескорыстной взаимопомощи, бесконечной заботы **внутри названных
>   семей**, что, на мой взгляд, этот феномен заслуживает глубокого
>   уважения.

Спасут ли меня кавычки:  *внутри "названых" семей* (так я расправлюсь с лишним "н")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется удачным ваш вариант с кавычками — **"названые семьи"**  (кавычки обозначат условность сочетания, которое не является общепринятым).

Здесь скорее имеются в виду не "названые" родители, а именно семьи, связанные подобными отношениями.

Лучше писать **одну букву Н**, в этом случае слово более узнаваемо.

Answer (score 0):

> ...так много бескорыстной взаимопомощи, бесконечной заботы внутри
>   названных семей.

«Названные родители», — так правильнее. Те, кто принимают на себя заботы в случае ухода из жизни всех родных:

*Так много бескорыстной взаимопомощи, бесконечной заботы названных родителей или родственников.*

(Кумом в Сербии, а также в некоторых областях Украины и России по странной мистической традиции называют крёстного отца, откуда и происходит особое к нему отношение.)

Comment: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x